# ERROR ANDROID STUDIO E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need help, i have an error, that is this:  E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

CODE:

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

```
    recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    fuser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    usersList= new ArrayList<>();

    reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(fuser.getUid());
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            usersList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chatlist chatlist= snapshot.getValue(Chatlist.class);
                usersList.add(chatlist);
            }

            chatList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void chatList() {
    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUsers.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user= snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                for(Chatlist chatlist : usersList){
                    if(user.getId().equals(chatlist.getId())){
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
            userAdapter= new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, true);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow the approach:

1. Create an empty adapter the same time you set LayoutManager for the RecyclerView: Save it as field of your Fragment:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
userAdapter= new UserAdapter(getContext(), new ArraysList<>(), true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
```

2. When data is ready, populate the adapter and notify:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   /// origin code here

  // reset data in adapter and not re-creating adapter:
  userAdapter.setItems(mUsers);
  getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged());
 // instead of userAdapter= new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, true); recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to argue the case that you can simply ignore the warning as that's all it is. Your recycler adapter does get created and applied to the RecyclerView when you have some data to display.

Comment: yes it's working fine by ignoring mentioned error.but is it true to ignore this error and such errors??

Comment: All I can add to the above answer is that I have places in my codebases where this warning does occur at times and I'm fine with it. For example, when `onCreate()` is called in an activity the adapter is not yet set but after that I observe a LiveData instance and *then* the adapter gets set to the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

## For kotlin(Fragment):

```
recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```