# Is there a way to prevent the skipping of layout for the recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Basically the app it's just a simple to do list, but when I add new task to do, it appears on firebase, but not on my app, giving the error
"E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout".
I tried to fix it following the answers here on stackoverflow but none of them helped me, probably I was wrong to adapt the adjustments to my code. I'm just learning and this is my first project, I was following a tutorial to do it.
Anyway, this is the **MainActivity.java**:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        

        buttonadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AggiungiPiattoAttivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });

        //working with data
        ourdoes = findViewById(R.id.ourdoes);
        ourdoes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<MyDoes>();

        //get data from firebase
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(URL).getReference().child("AppLista");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //set code to retrive data and replace layout
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    MyDoes p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MyDoes.class);
                    list.add(p);
                }
                doesAdapter = new DoesAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
                ourdoes.setAdapter(doesAdapter);
                doesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //set code to show an error
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

**This is the class where I add a new to do task:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aggiungi_piatto_attivity);

    buttonaddnewpiatto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //insert data to database
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(URL).getReference().child("BoxDoese").child("Does" + doesNum);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                dataSnapshot.getRef().child("titledoes").setValue(addnamenewpiattosetted.getText().toString());
                dataSnapshot.getRef().child("descdoes").setValue(adddescnewpiattosetted.getText().toString());
                dataSnapshot.getRef().child("qualcosaalpostodiunimmagine").setValue(addrecipenewpiattosetted.getText().toString());

                Intent a = new Intent( AggiungiPiattoAttivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

**This is my adapter class:**

```
public class DoesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DoesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<MyDoes> myDoes;

    public DoesAdapter(){
    }

    public DoesAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<MyDoes> p ){
        context = c;
        myDoes=p;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_does, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.titledoes.setText(myDoes.get(i).getTitledoes());
        myViewHolder.qualcosaalpostodiunimmagine.setText(myDoes.get(i).getQualcosaalpostodiunimmagine());
        myViewHolder.descdoes.setText(myDoes.get(i).getDescdoes());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myDoes.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView titledoes, descdoes, qualcosaalpostodiunimmagine;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titledoes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titledoes);
            qualcosaalpostodiunimmagine = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.qualcosaalpostodiunimmagine);
            descdoes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descdoes);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have other classes but to not put too much code I avoid to put them, they should not be relevant.

Comment: and ... what error are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Excuse me if the question is a bit confusing and not very precise, but I was having trouble posting it, because there are many similar questions (which I have already seen but I didn't help) anyway I edited the question, now there is the error, sorry again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty adapter the same time you set `LayoutManager` for the `RecyclerView`: Save it as field of your class:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
doesAdapter = new DoesAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(DoesAdapter);
```

When data is **ready**, populate the adapter and notify:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   /// origin code here
  for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                MyDoes p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MyDoes.class);
                list.add(p);
            }
  // reset data in adapter and not re-creating adapter:
  doesAdapter.setItems(list);
  doesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 // instead of  doesAdapter = new DoesAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(DoesAdapter); 
}
```

**Source**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251986/12596713

Comment: ok first of all thanks for the reply. 
I suppose these changes should be done in MainActivity.java, so after I set the layoutmanager I added the three lines you wrote and then in the ondatachange method I added what you wrote, removing the assignment line as you said. But the error persists.

Maybe I should do the second part on the class that manage the new data? but in that class I have not the reference to the recyclerview... because the recyclerview is a field of MainActivity.java

Comment: the whole code is to place in the main class.

Comment: Yeah MainActicity is the main class so I did right

Comment: ok it worked, the problem was on firebase too, with your solution and some changes on the databse it works, thanks a lot man!

Comment: Firebase callbacks are already invoked on the main/UI thread, so this `MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> doesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged());` can be simplified to `doesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.